# infinite loop using useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

hi im getting an infinite loop with useEffect.. it seems it is not displaying any children prop instead it loops on an empty prop.

```
import {useEffect , createContext  , useState} from "react"
import {auth} from '../../firebase'
export const AuthContext = createContext() 

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children}) =>{
  const [currentUser , setCurrentUser]  = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth ,(user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
    })

    return ()=>{
      unsubscribe()
    }
  }, []);
  return(
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{currentUser}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

P.S this is the only code that use `useEffect`

Error:
`react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`

Comment: Can you add error logged in console.

Comment: Have you tried to put `const unsubscribe` outside useEffect and set it in dependancy array ?

Comment: I have couple questions : 1- where is the import of `onAuthStateChanged` function
2- did you try to import `onAuthStateChanged` function in the dev dependencies of useEffect ? and if it's a function has been written by you , did you wrap it with useCallBack hook ?

Comment: Could you please provide more context? Because user could be undefined initially, are you sure there are not side effects on the children components?

Comment: cant reply to the comments i think there no reply buttons

Comment: Agree with the others this is missing some code and context.  onAuthStateChanged is probably setting state itself so you are getting in this loop.  its possible that if you check for an empty user  before setting it then that could fix it.